# Does this system of PDE's always admit a solution?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, linear-pde

Let $P(u,v)$ be a smooth real function defined on some open simply connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and satisfying the PDE $P_{uv}=P$.

Consider the following system of PDE's for a function $F(u,v)$:

$$ (1) \, \, \, F_{uu}+F=P \\ (2) \, \, \,  F_{uv}=F$$

> Does this system always have a  local solution? That is, is it true that for any smooth $P$ satisfying $P_{uv}=P$, there is a solution $F$ to the system above?

Note that the equation $P_{uv}=P$ is hyperbolic, so has many solutions locally.

---

**Edit:**

Here I am verifying some of the details in [Harry49's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3534246/104576):

> 1. First, let's check that $$F(u,v) = F_0(v-u) + \int_0^u P_v(u-\tau, v - \tau) \, \text d \tau$$ form a solution to the derived equation $F_{u} + F_{v} = P_v$.

[Differentiating under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), we obtain

$F_u=-F'_0(v-u)+\int_0^u \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\big(P_v(u-\tau, v - \tau)\big) \,d \tau+\left.P_v(u-\tau, v - \tau)\right|_{\tau=u}=\\-F'_0(v-u)+ \int_0^u P_{vu}(u-\tau, v - \tau) \, \text d \tau+P_v(0, v - u) \tag{3}$

and similarly

$$ F_v=F'_0(v-u)+\int_0^u \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\big(P_v(u-\tau, v - \tau)\big) \,d \tau=\\F'_0(v-u)+\int_0^u P_{vv}(u-\tau, v - \tau) \, \text d \tau \tag{4}.$$

Summing $(3),(4)$, we obtain

$$ F_u+F_v=\int_0^u P_{vu}(u-\tau, v - \tau)+P_{vv}(u-\tau, v - \tau) \, \text d \tau+P_v(0, v - u). \tag{5}$$

Now, write $G=P_v$. Then, rewrite the last equation as
$$ F_u+F_v=\int_0^u G_u(u-\tau, v - \tau)+G_v(u-\tau, v - \tau) \, \text d \tau+G(0, v - u). \tag{5'}$$
Now, write $\alpha(\tau)=(u-\tau, v - \tau)$; then $$\frac{d}{d\tau}G(\alpha(\tau))=\langle \big(G_u(\alpha(\tau)),G_v(\alpha(\tau))\big), \alpha'(\tau) \rangle=-\big(G_u(\alpha(\tau))+G_v(\alpha(\tau))\big),$$ so $(5')$ becomes $$ F_u+F_v=\int_0^u G_u(\alpha(\tau))+G_v(\alpha(\tau)) \, \text d \tau+G(0, v - u)=\\ -\int_0^u \frac{d}{d\tau}G(\alpha(\tau)) \, \text d \tau+G(\alpha(u))=\\ G(\alpha(0))-G(\alpha(u))+G(\alpha(u))=G(\alpha(0))=G(u,v)=P_v(u,v). \tag{5''}
$$

> 2. Now, let's see when this $F$ solves the original system of equations $(1),(2)$ (This would give us a condition on $F_0$):

As demonstrated above, $F$ satisfies $F_{u} + F_{v} = P_v$. Differentiating w.r.t $u$, we get $F_{uu} + F_{uv} = P_{uv}=P$. One can easily show that this last equation together with either $(1)$ or $(2)$ implies the third one. (In fact any two out of these three imply the remaining equation). Thus, *it suffices to check when $F_{vu}=F$.*

Differentiating equation $(4)$, we get
$$ F_{vu}=-F''_0(v-u)+P_{vv}(0,v-u)+\int_0^u P_{vvu}(u-\tau, v - \tau) \, \text d \tau=\\ -F''_0(v-u)+P_{vv}(0,v-u)+\int_0^u P_{v}(u-\tau, v - \tau) \, \text d \tau, \tag{6}$$

where in the last equality we have used the fact that $P_{uv}=P$ and the equality of mixed derivatives, to deduce that $P_{vvu}=P_v$.

Using equation $(6)$ and the defining formula of $F$, we see that $F_{vu}=F$ if and only if 
$$ F_0(v-u)+F''_0(v-u)=P_{vv}(0,v-u).$$

> Writing $H(t)=P_{vv}(0,t)$, we get the equivalent ODE
>   $$ F_0(t)+F_0''(t)=H(t).$$
>
> ---

*Earlier (unsuccessfull) attempts:*

1. I tried fixing the variable $v$, and then treat  $F_{uu}+F=P$ as an ODE in the $u$-variable, then get a family of solutions parametrized by $v$, and plugging them into $F_{uv}=F$.
2. Set $G:=F_u$; then $G_u+G_v=P$ and $G_v=F$...(not sure how to continue from here).

---

*Comment:* The system $(1),(2)$ implies $P_{uv}=P$. However, $P_{uv}=P$ plus either one of the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ do not imply the other one.

Comment: No, it only implies that $Q_{uv}=Q$ for $Q=F-P$. However, the equation $Q_{uv}=Q$ has non-zero solutions (e.g. $Q(u,v)=e^{u+v}$ ) so $Q$ does not need to be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiating $(1)$ w.r.t. $v$ gives
$$
F_{uuv} + F_{v} = P_{v} .
$$
Differentiating $(2)$ w.r.t. $u$ gives
$$
F_{uvu} = F_{u} ,
$$
so that the equality of mixed derivatives gives $F_{u} + F_{v} = P_v$. The method of characteristics provides solutions of the form
$$
F(u,v) = F_0(v-u) + \int_0^u P_v(u-\tau, v - \tau) \, \text d \tau
$$
where $F_0$ is an arbitrary function. The unknown $P$ solves a second-order linear hyperbolic PDE in its canonical form $P_{uv} = P$. Some solutions of the form $P(u,v) = A e^{ku + v/k}$ can be found by separation of variables.